# Какая разница между id и class в css

Tags: css

Сообственно говоря, вопрос сформулирован в названии темы?

Comment: `id` уникальный, а `class` нет. И у объекта может быть несколько class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- id имеет более высокий приоритет в css, чем class.
- id должен быть уникальным на весь html документ.
- class можно комбинировать с другими классами, через пробел, а id нет.
- id создаёт объект с таким же именем в [пространстве window](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object), доступ к которому можно получить через js. Например:

  ```html
  <p id="some_id">Мир</p>
  <p id="ff-ff">Привет</p>
  <script>
      some_id.innerHTML = 'Иван';
      alert(window["ff-ff"].innerHTML);
  </script>
  ```

Comment: Четвертый пункт про то, что создается объект - не верен, проверьте сами. Так же по стандарту id может содержать "-", что воспринимается как оператор разности в js. И еще не зря же существует метод `document.getElementById()` :)

Comment: понял. всем спасибо

Comment: @Alex проверил и обновил ответ. Вы тоже проверьте.

Comment: @Alex, к полю с `-` в названии нельзя обратиться через точку, в остальном это такое же поле доступное через `[]`

Comment: @Alex, добавил в ответ ссылку на говорящий про это кусок стандарта, если не верите, посмотрите там)

Comment: @Alex я тоже сперва не поверил, но открыл js-консоль и вбил - и таки есть)

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш внимание)